# NavMeshAgent is still moving after stopped in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was making a simple 3D project with Unity3D. But when using `NavMeshAgent`, I got a problem that `NavMeshAgent` was still moving even though it had been stopped. Why this situation is happening, and how can I get rid of this?

Below is GIF:[image]

And this is a picture of `NavMeshAgent` of that red cube, if it needs:

[image]

This is a source code attached to that:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class PathFinder : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject target;
    private NavMeshAgent nav;

    void Start() {
        nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        if (target != null) nav.SetDestination(target.transform.position);
        nav.isStopped = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any form of animation attached? Have you considered setting the destination to where you are?

Comment: Sorry for a late answer, but there is no animation attached. And setting the destination to its own position makes it spin or shake.